# PHP, switch case returned undefined variable

Tags: php, loops, switch-statement

Hy,

I got switch case inside function when but when i call it, i got error Undefined Variable and i don't know why (i use PHP 8)

```
private function getIDFromBrand() {
    switch ($this->brand) {
        case "Niky":
            $id = 1;
            break;
        case "Pumo":
            $id = 4;
            break;
        case "Coke":
            if ($this->typecoke== 0) {
                $id = 2;
            } else {
                if ($this->typecoke== 1) {
                    $id = 3;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "Tomato":
            $id = 5;
            break;
        case "Riles":
            $id = 6;
            break;
        case "TEST":
            $id = 7;
            break;
    }

    return $id; // Error Undefined variable $id
}
```

When i declare $id at the top of my function, like

> $id = null

or

> $id = 0

The switch doesn't update it, so it will return null or 0, it will return the declared value.

Comment: What are the values for `$this->brand` and `$this->typeCoke`? That should tell you why none of the `case` statements matches your criteria.

Comment: Add a default to make sure it's initialized if none of the cases match.

Comment: its an object, it is not empty

Comment: even if i add default, i still have undefined variable error

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement has no `default` branch, so if `$this->brand` is, say, "Stack Overflow", it will not run any of the statements, and `$id` will never be set.

See [the PHP manual for the `switch` statement](https://php.net/switch):

> A special case is the `default` case. This case matches anything that wasn't matched by the other cases.

Similarly, if `$this->brand` is "Coke", but `$this->typecoke` is, say, `42`, it will not match either of the conditions in that branch.

```
switch ($this->brand) {
    case "Niky":
        $id = 1;
        break;
    case "Pumo":
        $id = 4;
        break;
    case "Coke":
        if ($this->typecoke== 0) {
            $id = 2;
        } elseif ($this->typecoke== 1) {
            $id = 3;
        } else {
            $id = -1; // WAS PREVIOUSLY NOT SET
        }
        break;
    case "Tomato":
        $id = 5;
        break;
    case "Riles":
        $id = 6;
        break;
    case "TEST":
        $id = 7;
        break;
    default:
        $id = -1; // WAS PREVIOUSLY NOT SET
        break;
}
```

Comment: Even with a default, i still have undefined variable, $this->brand will never be empty bcz i have several function who check this before, so $this->brand will always exist and $this->typecoke too

Comment: @Sinay I didn't say they were *empty*, I said they didn't match the specific values you are checking for.

Comment: Actually i did another test, i remove everything except the first case (actually $this->type is "Niky") even with only ONE case i got undefined variable

Comment: @Sinay In that case, please edit your question to include a complete [mre], because based on the code you provided, that would work fine: https://3v4l.org/a4ZH3